# What is the relationship between id and numpy.shares_memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In Python 3.x, I don't understand the relationship between `id` and `shares_memory`. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20)
print(a)
print(id(a))
b = a[::2]
print(b)
print(id(b))
np.shares_memory(a,b)
```

This is the output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
2784148965456
[ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18]
2784148964736
True
```

`shares_memory` evaluates to True, but their `id` values are different. Why is that?

Comment: They are unrelated

Comment: shares_memory refers to the data buffers; it returns True if those overlap, which is the case if but doesn't require that the base pointers a.data, b.data are equal---id returns, in the current C implementation of python, the address of the object itself---as basic operations such as slicing create array views, i.e. derived arrays which reference but do not copy the original array's data, memory sharing is rather frequent

Answer (score 1):

Build-in function id() returns an unique identifier for Python object which is ndarray in your case. If two objects have the same id then they are .. the same object.
The common way it implement id() in Python is to return pointer to the object cast to an integer number.

The data stored in ndarray is a **separate** object. There can be multiple ndarrays that share the same memory i.e. results of slicing. You can check the actual address of the the first element in ndarray's data with `arr.__array_interface__['data']`.

In order to trace the true owner of the data you can use `base` attribute:

```
>> a = np.zeros(10)
>> b = a[1:]
>> c = b[1:] # c is made from b not a!
>> a.base is None
True
>> b.base is a
True
>> c.base is a
True
```

Note that the data address and id() may be likely similar numerically because they are often created by consecutive allocations.

Two ndarray *share memory* if they share the base. Note that if object's base is None then the base is the object itself. Moreover, the array buffers must share at least one byte.

Comment: Statements that are pure guesswork should be clearly marked as such. `np.shares_memory` does quite a bit more than your code. Try `a = np.eye(2); np.shares_memory(a[0],a[1])` to get an idea.

Comment: @PaulPanzer .You are right, the arrays share the base, but their ranges do not overlap. I've oversimplied the thing. I've tested that shares_memory() works even for interleaved slices. I'll update the post. Thank you for pointing the problem